# @Import all less files in a directory into a less files

Tags: less, laravel-elixir

I have my less files as in below directory structure

```
   vendor/includes/file1.less
   vendor/includes/file1.less
   vendor/includes/file1.less
   vendor/includes/file1.less
```

Id like to import into my main less file as in below directory structure

```
  vendor/main.less
```

Currently am using below @ import which does not work

main.less

```
@import "includes/";
```

any suggestions  ? 
Note : am using elixir to compile via gulp

Comment: See [`less-plugin-glob`](https://github.com/just-boris/less-plugin-glob).

Answer (score 1):

Just copying and detailing `seven-phases-max`'s comment as it was the answer I was looking for.

Use [`less-plugin-glob`](https://github.com/just-boris/less-plugin-glob):

1. Install the npm package with `npm install --save-dev less-plugin-glob`
2. Pass the plugin to the `less()` function call in your gulpfile:

   ```
   .pipe(less({
       plugins: [require('less-plugin-glob')]
   }))
   ```
3. Use glob patterns in your imports:

   ```
   @import "includes/*.less";
   ```